# Dual boot with separate hard drives. HD1 has Ubuntu 14.04 HD2 has Windows7

Tags: 14.04, dual-boot, grub2, windows-7

I'm running Ubuntu 14.04 and Windows 7 on my PC, both 64-bit. The way I use it is to turn off the PC and connect the Ubuntu HD if I want to use Ubuntu. If I want to use Windows, I disconnect the Ubuntu HD and connect the Windows HD.

Is there any way I can make a dual-boot without reinstalling either of the two OSes?

As I noted, they are on separate HD.

I want to use the Windows OS for some games that I can't get to work with Play on Linux and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Are you booting with BIOS or UEFI? If your PC is relatively new (post 2013) then chances are your are using UEFI. If you have UEFI correctly configured you can have both hard drives plugged in, and just go to the UEFI boot menu as your computer starts up to select between the two operation systems.

If you are using BIOS then just change or override the boot order in BIOS settings to the hard drive with the desired OS installed.